# changing HTML content in PHP

Tags: php

I am newer to PHP and I have a problem changing the `resultDiv` contents

```
if(mysql_num_rows($res)==0)
    {
           echo "<script>document.getElementById('resultDiv').innerHTML='No such flight';</script>";
          // echo "<script>alert('No Such filght');</script>";
           echo "No such flight";
    }
else{
    echo "<table border='1'><th>flight#</th><th>Dep. City</th><th>Arrival City</th><th>Dep. Date</th><th>Arrival Date</th><th>Total Seats</th>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
     echo "<tr><td>".$row['id']."</td><td>".$row['depCity']."</td><td>".$row['arrivCity']."</td><td>".$row['depDate'].
     "</td><td>".$row['arrivDate']."</td><td>".$row['totalSeats']."</td></tr>";
     echo "</table>";
    }
</div>
<div id="resultDiv">
Result Div
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please avoid to use [mysql_*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) function as it is deprecated in latest version. You can use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php) or `PDO`.

You can display message like this :-

```
<?php
    $message = (mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) ? 'No Such Flight' : '';
?>

<div id="resultDiv">
 <?php echo $message;?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
<div id="resultDiv">
<?php
   if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) {
       echo "No such flight";
   } else {
       echo "Flight found";
   }
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have **misspelled** "resultDiv" in get element by id, also define the div before the if condition.

```
<div id="resultDiv">
Result Div
</div>



 if(mysql_num_rows($res)==0)
 {
       echo "<script>document.getElementById('resultDiv').innerHTML='No such flight';</script>";
       echo "No such flight";
 }
```